# Which Version of Xcode is suitable for mac os yosemite

Tags: xcode, macos, ide

I am using mac os yosemite [hackentos] 10.10. I want to install Xcode on my Mac, but the current version of Xcode 8.3.3 needs macOS Sierra, and I am not able to upgrade to Sierra.

Which version of Xcode is suitable for Mac OS X Yosemite?

Answer (score 0):

> Which version of Xcode is suitable for MacOS Yosemite ...

Use Xcode 6 for MacOS Yosemite (10.10).

Xcode 6 is kind of disjoint. Its pretty typical considering Xcode supports OS X and iOS across OS releases. Xcode 6.0 - 6.2 was released for MacOS Mavericks (10.9). Xcode 6.3 - 6.4 was released for MacOS Yosemite (10.10).

It looks like Xcode 7.0 - 7.2.1 is applicable as well. Also see the [Xcode 5.0 - 6.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_5.0_-_6.x_.28since_arm64_support.29) and [Xcode 7.0 - 8.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_8.x_.28since_Free_On-Device_Development.29) support on Wikipedia.

If you need to use the command line to determine versions of what you have, then see [Determine xcode command line tools version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/180957/83961) on Apple Stack Exchange.